# How to penalize the SVM for one category in sci-kit learn library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have 10000 sample for one class whereas only 3500 sample of the other class.This is why I am facing class imbalance problem.Is there any penalized version of SVM in sci-kit learn library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVC, keyword `class-weight` in the `fit` method sets the parameter `C` to `C*value` where `value>0`.

Actually, `class weight` is a dictionary of the form of `class_label: value`.

Refer http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html (sec: 1.4.1.3)